# Top right cell in table is not showing

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

With the help of several people from Stack Overflow I've managed to almost perfect my webpage.

I have a PHP table that is pulling info from the database.  However, for some reason it is leaving the top right cell blank.  There are 3 columns and about 200 rows and the only cell that's showing blank is the top right one.

If someone could post the sample code of what to change then that would be great.  I'm sure it's something simple, I've just been staring at it too long most likely!

The table code is near the bottom:

```
<?php include("header.html"); ?>

<center>
<?php
    /*
        Place code to connect to your DB here.
    */
    include('database.php');    // include your code to connect to DB.

    $tbl_name="list";       //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "index.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 1001;                              //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT website FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination2\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">&lt; previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">&lt; previous</span>";  

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next &gt;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next &gt;</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>

    <?php
$i = 0;
echo '<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:1050px;"><tr>'; 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i ++;
    if ($i<=2)
    {
      echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
         <div><a href="http://www.test.com/check.php?site='.$row[website].'">'.$row[website].'</a></div>
       </td>'; 
    }

    else
    {       
      echo '</tr><tr>';
      echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><div><a href="http://www.test.com/check.php?site='.$row[website].'">'.$row[website].'</a></div></td>'; 
      $i = 0;
   }
}  
echo '</tr></table>';
    ?>

<?=$pagination?>
</center>

<?php include("footer.html"); ?>
```

Comment: I, for one, would need to see the generated HTML.

Comment: I wonder why this need to see the *actual markup in the browser* escapes so many people?

Comment: The increment value that is given inside of the while loop, which is then used to test for which display method is to be used, while this setup makes logical sense and is not what will be causing the issue, however, I must ask why it is even in there?  The value of $i does not break the loop or actually perform any different set of code whether it test is true or false as both code blocks are identical.  Could you please clarify the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move

```
$i ++;
```

after whole condition before end of loop:

```
        else
        {       
          echo '</tr><tr>';
          echo '<td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><div><a href="http://www.test.com/check.php?site='.$row[website].'">'.$row[website].'</a></div></td>'; 
          $i = 0;
       }
       $i++;
```

Comment: The problem was in that variable $i has already value 1, when you want to fill first row.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this while loop is

Set up flag($test)

First time round while loop $test = 0  and xxxx is executed.

At end of loop

$test is set to 1

Next time and subsequent time round loop yyyy is executed

```
$test = 0;
 echo '<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:1050px;"><tr>'; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    if ($test==0){
      xxxx;
    }else{
    yyyy,
    }
   $test =1;
 }
```

Comment: I'am sorry, David, but I don't understand where is an answer on question in your post?

Comment: The while loop executes a block of code while a condition is true.In this case while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) the loop executes until the last row of the query and the condition is false. In this case no counter $i is required. If you look at the logic of the question there are 2 conditions. Condition(1) the first condition is only valid in first row. Condition(2) is valid for all other rows.This is a classic use for a flag. Therefore the flag is set at 0 before the loop for condition(1) and set to 1 after first iteration of loop.

Comment: You are right with use of while statement in PHP. But in question, using of while statement is correct. Only using of variable $i is not much good, because incremental of $i is there too soon for the first row of output table (look at my answer, please).

Comment: Your answer works. But in the question the logic is not simple. There is only 2 states. 1)<td> tag & 2) <tr> tag. There is no need for increment.As I said this is a classic case of using flags. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(computing)

Comment: But there you have to add new line on each 3rd item from row, so you need some increment or other condition based on for example data from db. Or better rewrite code before while loop.

Comment: No increment required see comment from Bradley A. Tetreault

Comment: Whole code in question should be better written, but for new add line to table you alway need value 3 (0,1,2). Or sql queries should by rewritten to return rows with exactly three values each. And then to add flag for exit from loop in some cases, if it's needed.